# Is there an app to cast a vote or favorite of Everything?

Tags: web-apps

So, in websites like trakt.tv you can vote and favorite movies and tv shows; for music you have last.fm and many more... Then you have those for recipes, restaurants, anobii for books, amazon for any kind of product, etc...

But there is a web app for posting and tracking votes and favorites in every field? Say movies, music, restaurants, teas, apps, and everything else?

Once there was Glue app, but now it doesn't exists anymore. Is there something similar?

Comment: Not as an answer because it is not a web app: [Jotly](http://www.jotly.co/) is a phone application which allows you to rate everything.

Comment: If somebody want to give it a try and write an answer: I found [an article about Exxempt.com](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/07/exxempt-rating-website_n_6809378.html) which allows you just to do what you ask (or seems to according to the article). [The website](http://exxempt.com/) seems to be down at the moment, though.